# What is the workflow for compiling one file using rebar3?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell, rebar3

`rebar3` seems to recompile everything every time.

Often I am only modifying *one* file. That's the file I want to recompile, I know everything else is fine.

What is the workflow for doing this? Ideally I could do it from the Erlang shell. Rebar3 already knows my include paths and build directory with the beams in it, how can I take advantage of Rebar's knowledge so I don't have to type it all into the shell over again as arguments to `c(File, Opts)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that rebar3 avoids recompiling up-to-date modules (although it checks them).

That being said, I think the most popular option (and suitable for your needs) is using [this plugin](https://github.com/vans163/rebar3_auto).
In my case, I have a set of scripts to set up `inotifywait` and bring up the whole release down and up again. I also often create shell functions if I need to compile often:

```
4> C = fun() -> c('my_awesome_module', []) end. 
#Fun<erl_eval.45.97283095>
5> C().
{error,non_existing}
```